# How to set a file upload monthly quota on a role basis in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users, files

I'm using Drupal 7 and I'm quite a newbie here.

I'm building a small sharing/social network site where users will be able to upload different kind of files (mainly, pictures and zipped archives, but I'm not limiting the kind of files one can upload).

Is there a way to set a per-user upload limit/quota (say, 1Gb/month) on a user role basis?

**Edit**

- Using Amazon S3 and similar services is a viable option.
- Users' privacy should be protected, i.e. they should be able to set
  access permissions on the files they upload (private, friends-only,
  public), and it would be interesting to have the "expiry" option,
  i.e. a shared file could expire and be automatically deleted from
  server after a while.
- I know there is IMCE module, I never tried it but from its
  description it seems a bit buggy and not so safe from a privacy perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) module allows, "configurable limits for user roles: file size per upload, directory quota, file extensions, and image dimensions."

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems, at present, the only precompiled option. I'm accepting it, although I think I'll write a module myself to plug the quota functionality into Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

[User Disk Quota](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_disk_quota) seems to do the job as well